# sign out issue on windows authentication Sharepoint 2013

Tags: windows-authentication, 2012

Scenario:

- I configured dual authentication (FBA, windows authentication)
- I logging through windows authentication into site.
- When i going to sign out from site, it gets error

here is the snapshot when going to sign out

[image]

after this error, i opened site again but it doesn't ask for credential, it means i didn't proper signout.

is there any solution to avoid this error and successful signout.

Thanks